# how to import hierarchical Library in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, libraries, rtsp

I am new in IOS and I want to add an External Library in my Project.

The Libary is inside the other folder i.e `ffmpeg/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h.`
I add Libavcodec folder in Project and include Library Like.

```
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
```

But it gives error

```
Error: libavcodec/avcodec.h not found...
```

Thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 0):

Just drag and drop the library in your project in xcode. and then you can import the files in any viewcontroller.

Comment: it gives error. When i used library avcodec.h from libavcodec its fine but inside avcodec.h other library will used i.e "libavutil/samplefmt.h" here its give Error. "libavutil/samplefmt.h" not found . Kindly help...